# How to capture the uploading workbook name in the native sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

Actually I am fetching some data from the xyz workbook to the native sheet, I want to capture the xyz workbook & the respective sheet name into the native sheet, any commands in vba ?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Name`, `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name`.  Check **[Workbook Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835568(v=office.15).aspx)**.

Comment: Its returning the current workbook/sheet name..I need the workbook name which I am uploading ..

Answer (score 0):

Try handling xyz file in variable.

```
Dim WB as Workbook
Dim workbookName as String, worksheetName as string

set WB = workbooks.open ("C:\file.xls")

workbookName = WB.Name
worksheetName = WB.Sheets(1).name
```

then you can assign those values to any cell